# Remove duplicate entry in undefined level in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XSL Transformation here is the question. If I have this xml file:

```
    <root> 
        <node id="a">
            <section id="a_1">
               <item id="0">
                    <attributes>
                        <color>Red</color>
                    </attributes>
               </item>
            </section>
            <section id="a_2">
               <item id="0">
                    <attributes>
                        <color>Red</color>
                    </attributes>
               </item>
            </section>            
        </node>

        <node id="b">
            <section id="b_1">
                <user id="b_1a">
                    <attribute>
                        <name>John</name>
                    </attribute>
                </user>

                <user id="b_1b">
                    <attribute></attribute>
                </user>

                <user id="b_1a">
                    <attribute>
                        <name>John</name>    
                    </attribute>
                </user>
            </section>
        </node>
 </root>
```

and i want the output to be like this:

```
<root> 
        <node id="a">
            <section id="a_1">
               <item id="0">
                    <attributes>
                        <color>Red</color>
                    </attributes>
               </item>
            </section>
            <section id="a_2">
               <item id="0">
                    <attributes>
                        <color>Red</color>
                    </attributes>
               </item>
            </section>            
        </node>

        <node id="b">
            <section id="b_1">
                <user id="b_1a">
                    <attribute>
                        <name>John</name>
                    </attribute>
                </user>

                <user id="b_1b">
                    <attribute></attribute>
                </user>

            </section>
        </node>
 </root>
```

And the problem is I don't know how deep the level can go but as long as it is on the same level and there is duplicate, we remove it. 
Is this possible to be done. I have been trying to fix this all day and haven't got a clue.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

cheers,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--If you want to remove any duplicate element (not just user,
  change the match to: match="*[@id = preceding::*/@id]"-->
  <xsl:template match="user[@id = preceding::user/@id]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "on the same level", but if the element names also have to match, use this template: (Note: This template worked in Saxon 9.3, but did not in Xalan or Saxon 6.5.5.)

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id = preceding::*[name() = name(current())]/@id]"/>
```

**UPDATE:** Here's a template that seems to work in Xalan and Saxon 6.5.5:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[@id = preceding::*/@id]">
    <xsl:if test="not(@id = preceding::*[name() = name(current())]/@id)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```